# splashscreen doesn't work with Cordova 6.0.0

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, splash-screen

splashscreen doesn't work with Cordova 6.0.0, when I add preferences in config.xml after build it automatically removes the preferences and splashcreen is not working

[config.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt30f.png)

Location:  project\platforms\android\res

Comment: Which platform doesn't work? What preferences did you set? Show what you got.

Comment: Please post your config.xml and location where you have the splash images.

Comment: Android platfrom@dex, @Simon Prickett I have edited my question you can see the config.xml and location of the images and if know please explain the step by step to add splash-screen with example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add these preferences into `config.xml` in the project root: `project\config.xml`.
Cordova will propagate the preferences to all of your platforms' specific config.xml (that is why options are being removed on build).

Comment: I did the same but now its not finding the location of splash screen image, can you show me the path how to give. its showing like cp: no such file or directory: D:\Project folder\Project\res\screen\android\splash-po
rt-xhdpi.png @daserge

Comment: Your splash images resources should also live in the project root-relative path, i.e. `project\res\screen\android\splash-port-xhdpi.png`, etc. (according to the provided config.xml)